# OpenVPN .ovpn config file can't be imported by "OpenVPN Connect" on Windows

Tags: windows, openvpn

I have an OpenVPN server running on Debian, and I use [this Linux bash script](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Nyr/openvpn-install/master/openvpn-install.sh) to generate OpenVPN configuration/profile files for each of my clients.
It works perfectly for my MacOS client using Tunnelblick (the MacOS client software recommended by OpenVPN), and perfectly as well on Android with OpenVPN Android client.

However, on Windows, any OpenVPN config file is not readable by "OpenVPN Connect" Windows client. OpenVPN Connect says `Failed to parse profile: static_key_parse_error` when I try to import the config file.

My .ovpn config/profile file looks like this:

```
client
dev tun
proto udp
sndbuf 0
rcvbuf 0
remote XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX 1194
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
remote-cert-tls server
auth SHA512
cipher AES-256-CBC
setenv opt block-outside-dns
key-direction 1
verb 3
<ca>
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
XXXX==
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
</ca>
<cert>
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
XXXX==
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
</cert>
<key>
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
XXXX==
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
</key>
<tls-crypt>
</tls-crypt>
```

Comment: You're missing the `tls-crypt.psk` output in-between `<tls-crypt>` and `</tls-crypt>`.

Comment: Just an FYI, you're running an inefficient OpenVPN server setup: AES128 will remain uncrackable until at least 2030, so all you're doing is massively slowing throughput to a crawl by using AES256. TLS ciphers are only configured in the server's config, but if you're not using TLS EC ciphers, they're vastly more efficient [higher throughput] than SSL and `tls-version-min` should be `1.2` [server] (unless a lower version is necessary). `compress lz4` and `tun-mtu 48000` should also be utilized. Tuned config [examples](https://github.com/JW0914/Wikis/tree/master/Scripts%2BConfigs/OpenVPN)

Comment: Thanks! Not sure I understand though. Is the AES256 choice done by the script (https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Nyr/openvpn-install/master/openvpn-install.sh) I run, or something else?

Comment: That it is: Lines 375 & 448.  Also, `key-direction` is [not required](https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/Openvpn24ManPage) with `tls-crypt`... I still have it in my example client config, so it may be an oversight or I may have come across an issue... either way, I'd recommend testing a client without it, changing client `verb 5` first, then reviewing the client's log.  _**Note:** I seem to recall an issue with Apple products and `lz4` compression, but I could be misremembering... you'll want to do a few minutes of research on Google before implementing that on a Mac._

Comment: Thanks, will change that. Back to my issue, it seems that there is no `/etc/openvpn/server/tc.key` file on my server. Could that explain the script not creating the `tls-crypt.psk` output in the client config file? If yes, I assume maybe it was deleted for some reason, after it correctly created the other config files for the other clients. Also, what is `tls-version-min` and where to edit it?

Comment: Command to create `tc.key` is on Line 464, whereas the client config `tls-crypt` section is created on Line 225 _(i.e. there's no `tc.key` that's been created at that point)_.  Move all your client config sections below the server setup section & that should resolve the issue.  `tls-version-min` tells the server the minimum TLS version that must be used for the TLS ciphers _(OpenVPN 2.4 added EC TLS cipher support, so TLS EC ciphers should be used [example server config Line 110], with SSL ciphers as a fallback)_; valid options are `1.0`, `1.1`, or `1.2`.  Refer to the man page linked above

Comment: @bolino Just a thought here and something simple to test, but perhaps on the Windows system, the configuration file needs to have `CR/LF` end of line characters rather than just `LF`. I'm not certain if this is the problem, but convert the end of line characters of the generated config file you use on Windows to use 
"Windows" end of line character rather than the Linux end of line characters. You can use Notepad++ to convert this easily or else just google "convert LF to CRLF Windows" or something like that. Tighten up all leading and trailing space too in case that's an issue.

Comment: I've reinstalled OpenVPN server, it seems I now have `tc.key` created on my server, and thus the script is now successfully creating the `tls-crypt` section without changes. Strangely enough, it seemed that before reinstallation, I had a `tc.key` replaced by a `ta.key` file. That could explain the missing `tls-crypt` section. FYI @JW0914 I've created a fork of the original script: https://github.com/bolinocroustibat/openvpn-install, trying to apply your other advices, starting by AES128.

Comment: The only difference in `ta.key` vs `tc.key` is the name of the file and the naming for the inline xml content - the file content is the exact same.  To keep things sane and prevent anyone from becoming confused, I always use a naming version of `tc.key`, `tls-crypt.key`, etc. as it ensures users know it refers to `tls-crypt` and not `tls-auth` _(which was depreciated in OpenVPN 2.4)_